# Need to remove duplicates values from array during foreach

Tags: php

Just wondering if you can help me out.
I have a column with rows of tags. In each row i have each tag separated with a comma and space.

for example: BMW M5, Leather Seats, 24 Inch Wheels, etc.

What i need to do is loop through the array, explode it, and then print the values to the page. So far I have been able to do it; however, it prints the duplicates.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
<?php   
$cleanTags = ($row_getTags['tags']);  
$cleanerTags = str_replace(', ',"-",$cleanerTags);  
$tagstr = ($cleanerTags);   
$tags = explode('-',$tagstr);  

foreach($tags as $tag)  
{   
echo "<li><a href=\"results.php?search=".str_replace("&nbsp;",'%20',$tag)."\" title=\"Find more stuff tagged:&nbsp;".$tag."\" class=\"tagLink\">".$tag."</a></li>";
}
?>
```

How can I go about removing duplicates from the array? I've tried array_unique with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance for your help!!!

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure that each tag is the same case, string length, etc...  meaing, are the string exactly the same character for character?  Might want to try setting all values to lowercase before trying array_unique.

Comment: At what point did you try `array_unique`?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, `array_unique` solves your problem. Like this:

```
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```

So... Can you show how did you try `array_unique`?

Answer (score 2):

If `array_unique` didn't do the trick (*I wonder how you used that*), here is one way:

```
function remove_duplicates(array $array){
  $tmp_array = array();

  foreach($array as $key => $val)  
  {
     if (!in_array($val, $tmp_array))
     {
       $tmp_array[$key]  = $val;
     }
  }

  return $tmp_array;
}
```

And now your code should be:

```
$cleanTags = ($row_getTags['tags']);  
$cleanerTags = str_replace(', ',"-",$cleanerTags);  
$tagstr = ($cleanerTags);   
$tags = explode('-',$tagstr);  

// remove duplicates
$tags = remove_duplicates($tags);

foreach($tags as $tag)  
{   
  echo "<li><a href=\"results.php?search=".str_replace("&nbsp;",'%20',$tag)."\" title=\"Find more stuff tagged:&nbsp;".$tag."\" class=\"tagLink\">".$tag."</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: `$my_array` should be `$tmp_array` shouldn't it?